# How to launch a JAR with runtime command from another JAR?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

This is the code i'm using:

```
public class CLASSNAME extends JFrame
{

public static String MYAPP = new String(Util.getWorkingDirectory() + File.separator + "MYAPP.jar");
public static File MYJAR = new File(MYAPP); //used in other sections of the code
```

then when i call the runtime command it won't start, it works on Linux but not on Windows (possibly working on MAC as well):

```java
public static final void launching() throws Exception {
      try {

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec (MYAPP);
        System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

EDIT: that's how i made the code work (hope will be helpful for someone else):

```java
public class CLASSNAME extends JFrame
{

public static String MYAPP = new String(Util.getWorkingDirectory() + File.separator + "MYAPP.jar");

//THE JFRAME CODE AND THEN:

public static final void launching() throws Exception {
try {
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");

        if(osName.startsWith("Win")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec (new String[]{"javaw","-jar",MYAPP});
            System.exit(0);
        } 
        if(osName.startsWith("Linux")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec (new String[]{"java","-jar",MYAPP});
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(osName.startsWith("Mac")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec (new String[]{"java","-jar",MYAPP});
            System.exit(0);;
        }


        }catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

in this way on linux also runs MYAPP even if has not been marked with a runnable bit

Comment: Have you tried exec("java -jar" + MYAPP) instead ?

Comment: try: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+MYAPP.getName());`

Comment: RE:Have you tried exec("java -jar" + MYAPP) instead ?-----
it stops working on linux, but not a big deal to fix it, the code checks which OS is on the machine at the beginning, so probably is going to be the solution, thank you

Comment: RE: try: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar "+MYAPP.getName());----- this gives an error: it is undefined for the type string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to execute a Java jar with Runtime.getRuntime().exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302309/trying-to-execute-a-java-jar-with-runtime-getruntime-exec)

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: and that's the solution :D thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

if you can run the command in terminal or cmd，it will be right.